# Slow query and composite index

Tags: mysql

The following query takes forever to complete.

There are indices for each of the fields showing up in the `WHERE` & `JOIN` statements, but I don't have a composite index on both `ship_to_id` and `bill_to id` for the first `JOIN`.

When that first join is on a single field only, the query completes in no time, as expected.

The `IN` statement is the bottleneck.

Does a composite index make sense in this case, or do I have to change the logic of the query? Thanks.

Here's the `EXPLAIN` for this query (struggling with the formatting):

```
1   SIMPLE  orders          ALL or4                                     1973557 Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
1   SIMPLE  taxonomy    eq_ref  PRIMARY             PRIMARY 62  datamart.orders.Item    1   Using where
1   SIMPLE  universe    index   mtot1               mtot1   4            856128 Using where; Using index; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop)
1   SIMPLE  customer    eq_ref  PRIMARY,cu4         PRIMARY 4   datamart.universe.customer_id   1   


CREATE TABLE ff_atl AS
SELECT

universe.customer_id        as ID,

orders.order_date           as orddt,
orders.order_sequence       as ordnum,
taxonomy.age                as prodage,
taxonomy.category           as prodcat,
taxonomy.source             as prodsrc,
orders.order_category       as channel,
orders.quantity             as quantity,
orders.price_after_discount as pad,
orders.number_of_issues_left as nIssuesLeft,
orders.number_of_times_renewed as nTimesRenewed,
orders.number_of_invoice_effort as nInvoiceEfforts,
case when orders.order_status in (1,2,3,4) then 1 else 0 end as cancelled,
customer.zip                as zipcode,
customer.create_date        as fordt,
orders.item                 as item,
orders.subscription_id      as subid
FROM
paid_cat_ATL universe INNER JOIN orders_raw orders      ON universe.customer_ID IN (orders.BILL_to_id,orders.SHIP_to_id)
                      INNER JOIN customers_raw customer ON customer.customer_id = universe.customer_ID
                      LEFT JOIN  products taxonomy      ON taxonomy.order_class = orders.item
WHERE orders.order_date <= STR_TO_DATE( '2012-08-10' , '%Y-%m-%d' )

ORDER BY universe.customer_id , orders.order_sequence
```

Comment: any reason you can't just do `WHERE orders.order_date < '2012-08-10'`? mysql can accept that date as is without having to force it into a native date.

Comment: A composite index would not help as it would still need to match on the 2nd part of the index without a match on the first part (so the index would be useless). MySQL will only use one index on an instance of a table in a query, hence separate indexes on the 2 columns do not help. The solution (until MySQL indexes get smarter) is the suggestion below by Joe Frambach (splitting the query into 2, each of which can utilise an index). However that may not be the only bottle neck so it would be best if you post an EXPLAIN of your query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do two queries and UNION them.

```
CREATE TABLE ff_atl AS
SELECT

universe.customer_id        as ID,

orders.order_date           as orddt,
orders.order_sequence       as ordnum,
taxonomy.age                as prodage,
taxonomy.category           as prodcat,
taxonomy.source             as prodsrc,
orders.order_category       as channel,
orders.quantity             as quantity,
orders.price_after_discount as pad,
orders.number_of_issues_left as nIssuesLeft,
orders.number_of_times_renewed as nTimesRenewed,
orders.number_of_invoice_effort as nInvoiceEfforts,
case when orders.order_status in (1,2,3,4) then 1 else 0 end as cancelled,
customer.zip                as zipcode,
customer.create_date        as fordt,
orders.item                 as item,
orders.subscription_id      as subid
FROM
paid_cat_ATL universe INNER JOIN orders_raw orders      ON universe.customer_ID = orders.BILL_to_id
                      INNER JOIN customers_raw customer ON customer.customer_id = universe.customer_ID
                      LEFT JOIN  products taxonomy      ON taxonomy.order_class = orders.item
WHERE orders.order_date <= STR_TO_DATE( '2012-08-10' , '%Y-%m-%d' )

UNION

SELECT

universe.customer_id        as ID,

orders.order_date           as orddt,
orders.order_sequence       as ordnum,
taxonomy.age                as prodage,
taxonomy.category           as prodcat,
taxonomy.source             as prodsrc,
orders.order_category       as channel,
orders.quantity             as quantity,
orders.price_after_discount as pad,
orders.number_of_issues_left as nIssuesLeft,
orders.number_of_times_renewed as nTimesRenewed,
orders.number_of_invoice_effort as nInvoiceEfforts,
case when orders.order_status in (1,2,3,4) then 1 else 0 end as cancelled,
customer.zip                as zipcode,
customer.create_date        as fordt,
orders.item                 as item,
orders.subscription_id      as subid
FROM
paid_cat_ATL universe INNER JOIN orders_raw orders      ON universe.customer_ID = orders.SHIP_to_id
                      INNER JOIN customers_raw customer ON customer.customer_id = universe.customer_ID
                      LEFT JOIN  products taxonomy      ON taxonomy.order_class = orders.item
WHERE orders.order_date <= STR_TO_DATE( '2012-08-10' , '%Y-%m-%d' )

ORDER BY universe.customer_id , orders.order_sequence
```

Comment: Wouldn't UNION duplicate transaction records where bill_to_id and ship_to_id are the same? UNION with SORT also impact query speed I think.

Comment: You're right, it would. `JOIN other_table ON some_column = ID AND other_column <> ID` then.

Comment: That would exclude those records (ship_to = bill_to).

Comment: Sounds like a three stage UNION is the way to go. Seems there should be a more elegant way to do this.

Comment: The elegant way would be for mysql to optimize it correctly :(

Comment: It's confirmed, the three UNIONs into a temporary table then sorting is much faster than using the IN statement above. Thanks Joe.